# Is COT FEE a Scam?

Tags: banking, scams, fees, fraud, legal

I read another question about the COT FEE Scam, but what if they're not asking you to log into their account?
I was working with A Private Money Lender & was supposedly approved for a $200,000.00 loan. They said they were having issues with Citibank getting it to transfer the loan into my Wells Fargo account, so they told me to open an account with an online bank that they have used before for their clients.
The money looked like it was deposited into this Financial Shore Online Bank, but when I tried to transfer my money to my other accounts, I couldn't do it... They said I have to pay a $3000.00 COT FEE before I can do any Money Transfers, or even get a check book or Debit Card!!!

Can anyone please help me with this? This is supposed to be my cash & I can't even access it... This can't be legal, right??? The Private Money Lender made me pay them a $3500.00 Processing Fee in the 1st place, just to get this so called loan!

Comment: You didn't get a loan, your $3500 is lost, and any more money you'd be giving them would be lost too.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back...That's what I'm afraid of, but there acting like it's real, cause there still saying I need to start payments in 6 months...

Comment: Do you think that the Private Money Lender & This so called bank are in cohorts?

Comment: There's no lender and there's no bank. You're being scammed.

Comment: It's all a scam. Report all the details to the FBI at www.ic3.gov and maybe the current scam websites can be shut down.

Comment: You got a $200000 loan from amn institution you never had heard of? Are there no reputable banks in your area?

Comment: The $200,000 loan was from a Private Money Lender, not an institution like a bank. There are a lot of Private Money lenders out there who are companies that are LLC's that lend money for Real Estate investing & it's quicker & lower interest rates than banks. They also aren't as hard to be approved for. The one I was using was an LLC, but unfortunately, it's hard to tell if they're legit. I thought I had done enough research on them, so they sounded ok to use.

Comment: @KarenKelly private lenders are usually more expensive than banks because they're taking more risks than banks. The rule of thumb is that if it sounds too good to be true - it probably is.